# TypeScript - multiple assertions

Tags: typescript, assert

I am trying to assert that multiple values are not `undefined` using TypeScript's `asserts` feature. While I am able to assert a single value, I am not able to assert multiple values by a single statement. See below.

```
function assert1(a1: any): asserts a1 {
  if (a1 === undefined) throw new Error()
}
function assert2(a1: unknown, a2: unknown) {
  assert1(a1)
  assert1(a2)
}

const foo = () => Math.random() < 0.5 ? 4999 : undefined

const a = foo()
const b = foo()

assert1(a)
console.log(a + 10) // works as expected, no errors


assert2(a, b)
console.log(a + b) // const b: 4999 | undefined, Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
```

I spent quite a long time with this but to no avail. Is it possible to make this work? Or do I have to stick with the traditional:

```
if (!a || !b || !c || !d ...) {
  throw ...
}
```

Thanks for your help and insights.

Comment: To assert a value a function must have an `asserts` signature. Your `assert2` has no, so that function call asserts nothing.

Comment: ..also you should check the type using `typeof a1 === 'undefined'`; unfortunately in JS `undefined` can be redefined... to assign to `undefined` you can use `a = void 0`

Comment: @BrunoGrieder typescript compiler would protect against it.

Comment: @zerkms ok; good to know

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of any solution to aggregate your assertions. Consider writing one `assertNotUndefined` and use it for each variable in your case a and b.

Comment: @zerkms Unfortunately it seems to me that I cannot add `asserts` signature for multiple arguments...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of asserting one single value, you also can assert conditions, which are truthy for the rest of the scope (more infos [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)):

```
function assert(condition: any, msg?: string): asserts condition {
    if (!condition) throw new Error(msg)
}

const foo = () => Math.random() < 0.5 ? 4999 : undefined

const a = foo()
const b = foo()

assert(a !== undefined && b !== undefined) // assert a and b are defined

console.log(a + b) // works; a: 4999, b: 4999
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoAoIIAmMsCAXCmAJ4A0iAtqgOYD8FqUWMYTAlBWkw5UiAmGKkkAbwBQieYhjBEuAIRiJ8ML0RQAFljgB3RGAwmAolkNZcjPjIC+MmWI6JgcOIgC8KnT4AfIgAssj6AHRYyOJw9Lg6ADyIAAwRAKyILIgALACcBYgU4IQYwNwYhC5uUCi+Hl4JrgjuAEb1nnBNMoLYeMiIqj5+JWUVhIgAZJOI7UMj4mNmhDoA9Kso6H11MRPtyFgYiKXlyzLrm0L9UzOtOpwg+lSiehgQANbVLXAANhgRPzgTFwAwA1LM1hsjHAsO9UABuFAUfIFOitZEFPJAA)

Comment: Thanks, have not thought of that.